# like %TEXTO% no full text search

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gostaria de uma ajuda referente a pesquisa utilizando o full text search no SQL Server.
Hoje tenho uma tabela que armazena materiais e estou fazendo uma pesquisa usando o full text search com contains ficando assim

```
SELECT * FROM MATERIAL WHERE CONTAINS(MAT_D040I1, '"FUSO*"' )
```

Com isso a consulta irá trazer todas os materiais que possuem iniciado por FUSO por exemplo

FUSO MEITECH EVA20048
BANDEJA EMENDA JG 24 FUSOES

porém gostaria de fazer uma pesquisa que não trouxesse somente o iniciado por e sim contém no meio da palavra (tipo like)

```
SELECT * FROM MATERIAL WHERE MAT_D040I1 like '%FUSO%'
```

com isso além de trazer os materiais FUSO MEITECH EVA20048 e BANDEJA EMENDA JG 24 FUSOES trariam PARAFUSO AJUSTE DII 2A RS e PARAFUSO SXT S/ENC MA 4X30MM

teria como fazer algo assim com full text search ao invés do like???

Caso ficou alguma duvida me informe que complemento as informações.

Comment: Não é só colocar o `*` também do outro lado da palavra ?

Comment: Não rsrs testei mas não funciona, pelo que li a vantagem do full text search é a utilização de index, se permitir um coringa no inicio não teria como utilizar a indexação, mas queria saber se existe uma outra forma de resolver isso